Does it make sense to argue that the English word adze ultimately derives from the Semitic root עצד?
Does it make sense to argue that the English word adze ultimately derives from the Semitic root עצד which refers to a tool or the verb that does precisely what an adze does.
I would add my suggestion assume that metathesis to explain the transposition of the final two consonants.
ADDED: To counter the impression that this a contextless etymology question without sufficient demonstration of assumption of systematicity, I want to point out that I am familiar with Theo Vennemann's work who finds evidence of Semitic influence on Germanic languages (which would include English).
ADDED: Wikitionary gives the etymology of the English adze as:

From Middle English adse, adese, from Old English adesa, eadesa(compare the oldest forms: adosa, adosan), assumed from Proto-Germanic *adisô, from Proto-Indo-European *h₃edʰḗs (compare Hittite [script needed] (atešša, “axe, hatchet”))


Vennemann's work on Semitic-Germanic contact is not taken seriously by Germanicists. It doesn't stand up to even superficial scrutiny

What @Tristan said. Google AI: Vennemann claims that Semitic is a substratum of Celtic languages, and that Punic, the Semitic language of classical Carthage, is a superstratum of Germanic languages. He claims to find evidence of this in loan words, structural features, and similarities between Norse and Semitic religions. Reminds me of another loony-tunes idea from someone whose name starts with the same first two letters. Worlds in Collision Immanuel Velikovsky. Both equally unconvincing.

The Latin word "ascia" refers to that woodworker's tool and the image is engraved on some Gallo-Roman tombs (funeral inscription on a tombstone - Fourvière museum). It is at the origin of 2 medieval French words "aisse" or "asse", that might have given adze.

@Graffito So where did the d come from?

It's possible, but doesn't seem likely.
"Adze" comes from Old English adosa, which doesn't have any obvious Indo-European etymology or cognates (though Hittite atešša "adze" is tantalizing). This means it's very possible that it was a borrowing from another language.
However, it would have to be a language that was in contact with Old English at the appropriate time, and there weren't a lot of Semitic languages in the area. A borrowing from Hebrew isn't impossible, but I don't know of any Hebrew word that looks especially close to adosa.
Given that tantalizing Hittite word, it's also possible it was inherited from Proto-Indo-European (and just didn't show up in the other branches)…or the Hittite was a coincidence, and it was a borrowing from some other language whose word for "adze" didn't end up attested anywhere else. Without more cognates, there's no real way to be sure what was going on before Old English. But a Semitic borrowing needs more assumptions than an inheritance or borrowing from a non-Semitic language, so Occam's razor suggests against it.

I'd say atešša is more than tantalizing. Both forms are completely accountable with *h3edhés- (or *h1odhés-) with regular development from there. The only potential issues are that they're different inflectional classes, but that's pretty common

more relevant is that there are also Semitic cognates of Hebrew maʿăṣād (clearly from the same root, and often glossed as adze) e.g. Arabic miʿḍad, and Ge'ez māʿĕḍad. This would suggest PS ʕ-ṣ́-d. A borrowed correspondence between Semitic tɬʼ (or tsʼ or ts) as simple s doesn't seem plausible

@Tristan True! The main reason I don't want to rule out borrowing is because we don't see any other traces of a verb root like *h₃edh- (or at least I haven't been able to find any with a quick search), and because *h₃e- would be expected to give ḫa- in Hittite, not a-. (Though *h₁edh- would handle that.) Given those discrepancies, I'm hesitant to reconstruct the root based on just two attestations.

yeah, I think the fact that we seem to have a simple s in Old English, rather than ss or ts (as we'd expect for a borrowing of Hebrew tsade), or ll (as we'd expect for a borrowing of earlier Semitic ṣ́), is more conclusive. Even if the Old English is a loan, Hebrew (or Semitic in general) is not a good candidate

@Tristan That would make a good answer! I didn't include it since I didn't know the Semitic root, but that is much more conclusive evidence.

you're probably correct, but imo this question is off-topic as a contextless etymology question without sufficient demonstration of assumption of systematicity

@Tristan Etymology is on-topic. If "No it doesn't make sense", preferably paired with "because..." is a reasonable answer, then it's a reasonable answer.

@AndrewLeach that comment was from before the question was migrated here when it was still on the Linguistics site
